# Asymptotic analysis of function $e^{-x^2/y}$

Tags: asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Given the expression $e^{-x^2/y}$, where $0 < y <1$ and $x \geq 0$, what is the tightest upper bound for this expression involving $y$? I would like to give a Big-Oh notation upper bound for this expression.

Comment: There is a suuuuuper tight upper bound: $e^{-x^2/y} \leq e^{-x^2/y}$. You cannot do better than that ;) Jokes aside. What kind of expresion are you looking for?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So, for example, I had seen that  $x.e^{-x/y} \leq y/e $. I was wondering if there was an equivalent for the expression I have above. So, I can express it in Big-Oh notation like $O(y)$ or something.

Comment: @ADA I have edited my original post to mention that I am after a Big-Oh upper bound there.

Comment: @ADA I realize that 1 would be the upper bound, but I am not sure if $g(y)=y$ is the right function, because say for $x=0,y=0.1$ in the original expression, I can get $1$, whereas your bound suggests it should be $0.1$, right? So, does $g(y)$ always dominate the expression?

Comment: Maybe you want to say which variable you want to send to which values and also in which order? You want to fix $y$ and send $x\rightarrow \infty$?